# Devise Handle Duplicate Sign In Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am fixing an application that needs to support duplicate sign in requests being sent to the server (for devise). The requests are sent via JSON. Currently, if I call the following more than once:

```
curl -v -b cookie.file -c cookie.file -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"username":"kevin","password":"password"}}' http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json
```

The first results in a `201` status code and the second results in a `302` that redirects to an HTML page. I've overridden the create method in `Users::SessionsController`, however the custom code is only called on the first POST (nothing happens for the second). Any way to get the second request to not performa redirect? Here is what I have so far:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    logger.info "Users::SessionController"
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up here as I had the same issue. The sign in for non-navigational formats weren't idempotent as I was redirected to the html-version if I was already authenticated.

This issue has been resolved as of 29th of September with [this commit.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/bc8fc2d4e4bcf3512da06e8d7cf534cd86f273c2)

As of today you have to use edge devise to get it working with your app.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'devise', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding SessionsController is not quite as seamless as other things in Devise. I *think* what you're asking for is pretty similar to [this article](http://jessehowarth.com/devise). It may not be exact, but it deals with how to create a pure-JSON sign-in environment.

Comment: My SessionsController create action is not being called on the second call (i.e. overriding it is not working). Any other ideas?

Comment: In that article about halfway down he mentions putting these directives in: `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false`
`config.navigational_formats = [:html, :json]`. I'm unable to experiment at the moment, but it seems like that is what would stop the http authentication request (and possibly the route forwarding).

Comment: Also, looking at the source for Devise, you may experiment with using GET instead of POST. And [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/badf166a8af3bd63/9e18eed786213fc5) is a good discussion of similar issues people are having.

Comment: Sorry for a third reply, but I just realized it may be even simpler than all this. Did you ever tell your `devise_for` statement to use your derived controller? It will definitely never call the new `create` method if it's not configured to use your own controller.

Comment: I tried setting the configuration parameters (no luck) and have setup the controller in my routes (it is being called for the 201 response). I can't change the HTTP verb (old iOS clients are connecting to the service).

Comment: Only other way I can think to do it would be to first send a `sign_out` before each sign-in, starting a new session each time. Other than that, I'm tapped out with my knowledge on this. The best I can say is that Devise is open source and pretty easy to follow, so it might be best to fork it and adapt for your particular scenario. It seems like it *should* do this out of the box, but just doesn't. Good luck!